# install linux distro with overwritting grub?

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, grub

Currently i am using linux mint 17.1 cinnamon

for some reasons i need to install xubuntu 14.04. So how to install xubuntu with overwriting GRUB.

**ie**. After installation I  should have linux Mint's Grub. **(Not Xubuntu Grub)**

*REASON OF ASKING* : I need   Xubuntu just for few days ! **(TO AVOID REPAIRING  GRUB AFTER DELETING XUBUNTU**)

IS THIS POSSIBLE ?

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu's installer asks for installing grub at a certain point. You can skip this step, reboot your machine, boot Mint, update-grub. It should find Xubuntu and add it to Grub.

Update grub again when you uninstall Xubuntu.

P.S. If you touch(ex. resize) the Mint partition during Xubuntu install this might throw you to grub rescue. In that case, I recommend resizing the partition first, updating grub and then go ahead with the Xubuntu install.